# show json data from foreach in view using core php

Tags: php, json

this is json data :

```
{"activities":[{"id":"23442","title":"coldplay","author":"ekkk@abc.com","modified":"due","action":"updated","date":"2017-05-31 12:59:27","message":"Updated the due date to 2017-07-12 10:30:00"},{"id":"23650","title":"Task For Timesheet viewer ","author":"tkkl@abc.com","modified":"assigneeView","action":"updated","date":"2017-05-31 09:51:35","message":"Accepted task"},{"id":"23650","title":"Task For Timesheet viewer ","author":"ekkk@abc.com","modified":"assigneeView","action":"updated","date":"2017-05-31 09:50:55","message":"Accepted task"},{"id":"23607","title":"project 3","author":"ekkk@abc.com","modified":"status","action":"updated","date":"2017-05-30 15:40:11","message":"Deleted task"},{"id":"23645","title":"naiman bug 2","author":"ekkk@abc.com","modified":"assigneeView","action":"updated","date":"2017-05-29 11:58:38","message":"Accepted task"},{"id":"23645","title":"naiman bug 2","author":"nkkk@abc.com","modified":"assigneeView","action":"updated","date":"2017-05-29 11:58:07","message":"Accepted task"}]}
```

To view this data in a table, i have used foreach loop in the view file. but it is not working showing, Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach(). This is how i did

```
<tbody>
            <tr>
            <?php foreach($notifications as $key => $value) {     ?>
                        <td><?php echo $value ?></td>
                    <?php } ?>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
```

Comment: you have to json_decode the string encoding the data first!

Comment: used  <?php echo json_decode($notifications) ?> and showing this error : Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string.

Comment: @Ekta You have to use it as object like $notification->activities for more look at my answer

Comment: @Ekta just add seocond parameter true in json_deocde

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it as

```
<tbody>
        <tr>
        <?php 
$notifications = json_decode('{"activities":[{"id":"23442","title":"coldplay","author":"ekkk@abc.com","modified":"due","action":"updated","date":"2017-05-31 12:59:27","message":"Updated the due date to 2017-07-12 10:30:00"},{"id":"23650","title":"Task For Timesheet viewer ","author":"tkkl@abc.com","modified":"assigneeView","action":"updated","date":"2017-05-31 09:51:35","message":"Accepted task"},{"id":"23650","title":"Task For Timesheet viewer ","author":"ekkk@abc.com","modified":"assigneeView","action":"updated","date":"2017-05-31 09:50:55","message":"Accepted task"},{"id":"23607","title":"project 3","author":"ekkk@abc.com","modified":"status","action":"updated","date":"2017-05-30 15:40:11","message":"Deleted task"},{"id":"23645","title":"naiman bug 2","author":"ekkk@abc.com","modified":"assigneeView","action":"updated","date":"2017-05-29 11:58:38","message":"Accepted task"},{"id":"23645","title":"naiman bug 2","author":"nkkk@abc.com","modified":"assigneeView","action":"updated","date":"2017-05-29 11:58:07","message":"Accepted task"}]}');
foreach($notifications->activities as $key => $value) {     ?>
                    <td><?php  echo $value->message;//or whatever you like  ?></td>
                <?php } ?>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Comment: Used your method. Now it is showing data as : Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 23442
            [title] => coldplay
            [author] => ekta@samayla.com
            [date] => 2017-05-31 12:59:27
            [message] => Updated the due date to 2017-07-12 10:30:00
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 23650
            [title] => Task For Timesheet viewer 
            [author] => twinkle@samayla.com
            [message] => Accepted task
        )

Comment: @Ekta Don't you know how to use this info ??

Comment: @Ekta Edited as per need

Answer (score 1):

you have to convert your json to array using json_deode after you can use foreach to print data

```
   $notification = json_decode('{"activities":[{"id":"23442","title":"coldplay","author":"ekkk@abc.com","modified":"due","action":"updated","date":"2017-05-31 12:59:27","message":"Updated the due date to 2017-07-12 10:30:00"},{"id":"23650","title":"Task For Timesheet viewer ","author":"tkkl@abc.com","modified":"assigneeView","action":"updated","date":"2017-05-31 09:51:35","message":"Accepted task"},{"id":"23650","title":"Task For Timesheet viewer ","author":"ekkk@abc.com","modified":"assigneeView","action":"updated","date":"2017-05-31 09:50:55","message":"Accepted task"},{"id":"23607","title":"project 3","author":"ekkk@abc.com","modified":"status","action":"updated","date":"2017-05-30 15:40:11","message":"Deleted task"},{"id":"23645","title":"naiman bug 2","author":"ekkk@abc.com","modified":"assigneeView","action":"updated","date":"2017-05-29 11:58:38","message":"Accepted task"},{"id":"23645","title":"naiman bug 2","author":"nkkk@abc.com","modified":"assigneeView","action":"updated","date":"2017-05-29 11:58:07","message":"Accepted task"}]}');

foreach ($notification->activities as $key => $value)
{
    echo $value->id."<br>";
    echo $value->title."<br>";
}
```

or just add true as second parameter to json decode then it will convert json to associate array so you can use it like your foreach

```
eg $notification = json_deocde('your_json',true);
```

now you can use it as your foreach

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to print an object, which is not a right thing to do. You should be printing scalars this object contains.

```
$s = '{"activities":[{"id":"23442","title":"coldplay","author":"ekkk@abc.com","modified":"due","action":"updated","date":"2017-05-31 12:59:27","message":"Updated the due date to 2017-07-12 10:30:00"},{"id":"23650","title":"Task For Timesheet viewer ","author":"tkkl@abc.com","modified":"assigneeView","action":"updated","date":"2017-05-31 09:51:35","message":"Accepted task"},{"id":"23650","title":"Task For Timesheet viewer ","author":"ekkk@abc.com","modified":"assigneeView","action":"updated","date":"2017-05-31 09:50:55","message":"Accepted task"},{"id":"23607","title":"project 3","author":"ekkk@abc.com","modified":"status","action":"updated","date":"2017-05-30 15:40:11","message":"Deleted task"},{"id":"23645","title":"naiman bug 2","author":"ekkk@abc.com","modified":"assigneeView","action":"updated","date":"2017-05-29 11:58:38","message":"Accepted task"},{"id":"23645","title":"naiman bug 2","author":"nkkk@abc.com","modified":"assigneeView","action":"updated","date":"2017-05-29 11:58:07","message":"Accepted task"}]}';

$data = json_decode ($s);
$notifications = $data->activities;

foreach($notifications as $key => $notification) {
    echo ($notification->id);
}
```